# Python: Plotting map in netCDF file using Basemap

Tags: python, netcdf

I'm working with netCDF file for plotting the map. However, I'm new to it and there is very little progress and all I did is learning some tutorials. I have some difficulties when overlaying color onto the map. Here is my code (with the downloaded [file](https://podaac-opendap.jpl.nasa.gov/opendap/allData/tellus/L3/grace/land_mass/RL06/v03/CSR/)):

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, cm
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = Dataset('filename','r')


lat = data.variables['lat'][:]
lon = data.variables['lon'][:]
time = data.variables['time'][:]
lwe_thickness = data.variables['lwe_thickness'][:]
data.close()


mp = Basemap(projection = 'mill',
         llcrnrlon=lon.min(), 
         urcrnrlon=lon.max(),
         llcrnrlat=lat.min(),
         urcrnrlat=lat.max(),
         resolution = 'c')

x, y = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)
x, y = mp(lon, lat)

mp.drawcoastlines()
mp.drawstates()
mp.drawcountries()
mp.drawmapboundary()

parallels = np.arange(0.,90,30.)
mp.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[1,0,0,0])

meridians = np.arange(-180.,180.,30.)
mp.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[0,0,0,1])

cmesh = mp.pcolormesh(x,y,lwe_thickness,shading='flat',cmap=plt.cm.jet,latlon=True)
cbar = mp.colorbar(cmesh, location='right')

plt.show()
```

Comment: What is the problem again ? Please update the question with the image you're expecting.

Comment: I want to plot the world map using those files ( overlaying data of netCDF files onto the world map). However, it's doesn't work

Comment: You might also like to try using cartopy instead of basemap.